# How to keep the titles fixed on a wordpress blog until the next post?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, position, blogs

I'd like to have the title and text of each article stay fixed on the left while the images of that post scroll. When you arrive to the next article I want the title to go back to the top of the first post and a new title to start with the new article.

As an exemple I found the cargocollective website in the favorites section: http://cargocollective.com/favorites

Here is a code I already found but I don't know how to include it inside the php loop
    http://jsfiddle.net/Tgm6Y/1447/

Below is my php code

```
<div id="content"">
<div class="post">

<div class="textpost">
<h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
<?php the_time('m.d.y') ?>  
<?php the_category(', ') ?> 
<?php ob_start();
the_content('Read the full post',true);    
$postOutput = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+./','', ob_get_contents());    
ob_end_clean();    
echo $postOutput;    
?>    
</div>

<div class="imagepost">
<?php
       $beforeEachImage = "<div>";
       $afterEachImage = "</div>";
       preg_match_all("/(<img [^>]*>)/",get_the_content(),$matches,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
       for( $i=0; isset($matches[1]) && $i < count($matches[1]); $i++ ) {
             echo $beforeEachImage . $matches[1][$i] . $afterEachImage;
       }
    ?>
</div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Below is my javascript:

```
var windw = this;

$.fn.followTo = function ( elem ) {
var $this = this,
    $window = $(windw),
    $bumper = $(elem),
    bumperPos = $bumper.offset().top,
    thisHeight = $this.outerHeight(),
    setPosition = function(){
        if ($window.scrollTop() > (bumperPos - thisHeight)) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: (bumperPos - thisHeight)
            });
        } else {
            $this.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 0
            });
        }
    };
$window.resize(function()
{
    bumperPos = pos.offset().top;
    thisHeight = $this.outerHeight();
    setPosition();
});
$window.scroll(setPosition);
setPosition();
};

$('#textpost').followTo('#textpost');
```

Comment: Please post all relevant code in the question so others down the road can benefit from your question.

Comment: Hi, I tried to help by sharing my code. I don't know if you took a look at http://cargocollective.com/favorites but the way the titles on the right move is exactly what I'd like to do